# Make applications scale correctly across multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-10

Recently I got a Surface Pro 4 and connected it to my 1920x1080p second monitor, making the monitor my second and the SP4's 2736x1824p monitor my main. A few days ago I realised that it would be smarter to use my large monitor as my main and my small built-in one as my second, so I adjusted that. Instantly, I saw that a lot of applications which scaled wrong fixed themselves, but only in a way. Now, applications on by original SP4 HDI monitor are now horribly fuzzy. I would switch back if it wasn't for the fact that if I did, a lot of applications would scale themselves wrong; for instance, Acrobat DC and PowerPoint used to make themselves really big with almost unusable interfaces on the second monitor. Now, they work on the second monitor but scale themselves really small on the SP4's.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: application developers must support per Monitor DPI scaling: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee308410(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 that’s what I feared.

Comment: yea, this is a new feature since Win 8.1, so it takes a lot of time to application developers to support it